# Упростить код JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я только начинаю изучать JS, возникла проблема, есть рабочий код, но сильно громоздкий и большой, помогите его упростить или уменьшить.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('check-1').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('item-1').disabled = !this.checked;
    };
    document.getElementById('check-2').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('item-2').disabled = !this.checked;
    };
    document.getElementById('check-3').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('item-3').disabled = !this.checked;
    };
    document.getElementById('check-4').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('item-4').disabled = !this.checked;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('main').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var row = e.target.parentElement

  if (row && row.classList.contains('chk-with-input')) {
    row.querySelector('.chk-dest').disabled = !e.target.checked
  }
})
```

```html
<main>
  <div class=chk-with-input>
    <input type=checkbox checked>
    <input type=text class=chk-dest>
  </div>
  <div class=chk-with-input>
    <input type=checkbox checked>
    <input type=text class=chk-dest>
  </div>
  <div class=chk-with-input>
    <input type=checkbox checked>
    <input type=text class=chk-dest>
  </div>
  <div class=chk-with-input>
    <input type=checkbox checked>
    <input type=text class=chk-dest>
  </div>
  <div class=chk-with-input>
    <input type=checkbox checked>
    <input type=text class=chk-dest>
  </div>
</main>
```